# android source code project make error

Tags: android-source

When I make aosp in the Ubuntu 14.04 with the cmd `make -j8`, I encounter an error and the error info are as follows.

- acp: failed reading 'out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_webview_java_with_new_resources_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar': Input/output error
- make: *** [out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_webview_java_with_new_resources_intermediates/emma_out/lib/classes-jarjar.jar] error 1

After searching in google, I find nothing related with this error. So anyone has encountered this error? Please help me.